# Taking a div from other website with PHP DOM

Tags: php, curl

Yesterday, I tried to take a div from other website to my web.

I want PHP to read the information that gives the div and compare between the string I give and the string that the website gives to me.

Here is my code:

```
//Blah, blah, blah
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.habbo.'.$hotel.'/home/'.$habbo));
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$motto = $xpath->query('//*[@class="profile-motto"]')->item(0)->textContent;
echo $motto;
if($code !== $motto){
    $num_habbo = 2;
}
//Blah, blah, blah
```

A example of a page:

> http://www.habbo.es/home/iEnriqueSP

The string I want to take is in "Mi perfil", between "Añadir amigo" and the avatar of the user.

When I try to show the string with `echo $motto`, PHP show nothing.

I don't know if cURL is necesary with PHP DOM but in my hosting's PHP Info cURL appears enable:

[image]

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice library for tasks like this.

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

It let's you parse html files and fetch both inner and outer text. The documentation should also be quite simple.

Comment: PHP send me two errors: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html()" and "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object" with the code that you gave to me.

Comment: Have u installed the Simple HTML DOM Parser?? download the source files from the link I shared, and include the same with `include('path/to/sourcefile')`

Comment: to make it simpler download and store `simple_html_dom.php` in the same directory as your php file, and add `include_once('simple_html_dom.php');` at the top of your file